# ExtJS 4.0 border layout panel width split drag in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, extjs4

I have a border layout panel with a center and west panel. I want to set the width of the panel with dragging the border `split: true`, but in IE11 it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea about this?

```
Ext.define("My.SplitPanel", {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel'

    leftPanel: undefined
    centerPanel: undefined

    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            layout: 'border',
            border: false,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: 'fit',
                region: 'west',
                collapsible: true,
                split: true,
                width: 250,
                items: this.leftPanel
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: 'fit',
                region: 'center',
                items: this.centerPanel
            }]
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chetanbh/3a0kyk1k/    
extjs-4.2.1 splitpanel in border layout is working fine in IE11.

Comment: Thx, but I have to use 4.0.7 unfortunately :'(

Comment: And here is an Example with 4.0.0 http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/window/layout.html I cannot find exactly 4.0.7. Your code looks good. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: If i use this my split panel class, the split bitween the items doesn't move in IE.